# Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object on line 7

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

okay Guys, i have searched the answer of this problem everywhere but had no luck in solving the problem. 
i created an xml document named questions.xml. A sample of codes is 
i.e

```
<Quiz>
    <topic text="Preparation for Exam">
        <subtopic text="Science">
            <question text="What is the largest planet in our solar system?"> 
            <answer num = "A" Text="Jupiter" correct="1"></answer> 
            <answer num = "B" Text="Venus" correct="0"></answer> 
            <answer num = "C" Text="Saturn" correct="0"></answer> 
            <answer num = "D" Text="Mars" correct="0"></answer> 
            </question>

            <question text="What is the smallest planet?" > 
            <answer num = "A" Text="Pluto" correct="1"></answer> 
            <answer num = "B" Text="Venus" correct="0"></answer> 
            <answer num = "C" Text="Saturn" correct="0"></answer> 
            <answer num = "D" Text="Mars" correct="0"></answer> 
            </question>
                </subtopic>
         </topic>
</Quiz>
```

then i made a form data which shows different question numbers and i have to select one question. i used radio buttons for selection and then defined a submit button named as "question". 
So when the user selects and submits any question then the radio button values either 0,1,2,3 etc is passed to another php page via POST method. 
Now in this new php page i have to show the desired question in the text fieldarea. 
the problem is i always get this stupid error "Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object on line 6". 
My codes are

```
<?php
    $condition= $_POST['question'];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("questions.xml");
    echo $condition;
    if ($condition=="0"){
        $question= $xml-> topic -> subtopic-> question[$condition] ->  attributes()-> text."<br>";
        echo "<form action='' method='post'> 
        <label for='question'> Question</label>
        <textarea name='question' id='1' cols='45' rows='5'>".$question."</textarea>
        <P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE='submit'> </form>";

        }
 ?>
```

Now there is no syntax error,  and the program is displaying echo $condition , but its not displaying the question is always displays "Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object on line 6". I am really pissed ..kindly help me.

Comment: Did you try casting your `$condition` to an integer?

Comment: `question[$condition]` is a non-object

Comment: @Ghommey: thats obvious.. the question is why is that the case... but a simple `var_dump($xml-> topic -> subtopic-> question)` would probably explain..

Comment: The code should work for condition `0`. Therefore it's probably a problem with the XML in `questions.xml`, I suspect it is not the same as the XML in the question.

Comment: @prodigitalson nope. but its giving me integer value. i can add the value of this $condition variable. Do u think its really really necessary?

Comment: @MrCode nope questions.xml is perfectly fine .

Comment: @user2083529: Yes it is... the keys will always be integers.

Comment: @prodigitalson yup you were 100 percent right ... casting solves the problem. thanks man ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$xml-> topic -> subtopic-> question[0]` exists and `$xml-> topic -> subtopic-> question["0"]` doesn't.

Casting `$_POST['question']` to integer would do the trick.

```
$condition= (int) $_POST['question'];
```

would work.

Comment: hahaha...thanks man ... it works .. u made me really really happy ... i am just laughing at my lack of knowledge lol... thanks man once again.

Answer (score 0):

Check first, you receive a user input, so it can be not set or can be any string.

Cast to int:

```
$condition = (isset($_POST['question'])) ? (int) $_POST['question'] : "some default value" ;

if (isset($xml-> topic -> subtopic-> question[$condition]) && is_object($xml-> topic -> subtopic-> question[$condition])){
  $question= $xml-> topic -> subtopic-> question[$condition] ->  attributes()-> text."<br/">
  //and so on.
}
```

Comment: nope its not working and i get a value from the Post. $condition is either 0, 1 ,2 ,3 .... i have 40 questions so its last value is 39... it works perfectly. but ur coding is somewhere i think i has no that much importance .